# Java int wont consider first 0

Tags: java, int, zero

i am trying to write a binary number class in java ..  but if i send an integer starting with 0 the number is not saved properly . i know what the problem is but i cant figure out a solution . in c++ i used a float instead of an int but in java that does not seem to work .

```
import java.util.*;


class BinaryNumber {

private boolean b[];


public void setBit(int index,boolean value){
 b[index]=value;
}

public boolean getBit(int index){
 return b[index];
}

public void clear(){    
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    b[i]=false;
}

public BinaryNumber() {
    b=new boolean[8];
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    b[i]=false;
    }   
} 

public void inputNumber(int a){

 if(a>11111111) {    
    System.out.println(" Exception Number to Large Nothing Entered ");
 }   
 else {

     int number=a;
     int c=7;
     int digit=0;

     for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
         digit=number%10;
             if(digit==1){ 
             b[c]=true;
             }
             else if (digit==0) { 
             b[c]=false; 
             }
             else { 
             System.out.println(" Only Binary Number Accepted "); 
             clear();
             i=8; //break
             }      
         number=number/10;
         c--;       
     }   
 }  
}

public void outputNumber(){     
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        if(b[i]==true){
            System.out.print("1");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("0");
        }
    }       
    System.out.println(""); 
}

 }


class Q5{
public static void main(String args[]){

BinaryNumber a=new BinaryNumber();  
a.inputNumber(00100110);    
a.outputNumber();

BinaryNumber b=new BinaryNumber();  
b.inputNumber(00100111);
    b.outputNumber();   

}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numbers starting with `0` are interpreted by Java as being in octal.

Comment: I Know that Problem but how can i solve this issue .. i know i can use a char array to take input but dont want to do that

Comment: Well, you could a) not use leading zeroes, b) use the [proper format for binary literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html), c) use `Integer.parseInt(String)`, which will always interpret its input as decimal.

Comment: small warning: binary literals of form `0b0001` will only work if you're building with JDK7.

Comment: int d=Integer.parseInt("00100110"); This seems to work at the moment but is this JDK7 exclusive  . and how does this work

Comment: No, that'll work on any version of Java; if you want to know how it's implemented, it's pretty much the predictable traverse-over-the-String-and-accumulate-results implementation.

Comment: @LouisWasserman int d=Integer.parseInt("00100110"); This seems to work at the moment but is this JDK7 exclusive . and how does this work

Comment: @lfti He's just answered that. Don't just repeat yourself.

Comment: I think digit=number%10; should be digit=number%2;

Comment: Depends on what the OP wants.  If he wants a hundred and one to translate into 3, then he wants decimal.